# Using loops or alternative to avoid repetitive lines of code

Tags: r

I have a data frame called TAS1, as follows:

```
TAS1     2000 obs. of 9862 variables

colnames(TAS1)=c(seq(as.Date('1979-01-01'), as.Date('2005-12-31'), by = 1))
```

The 9862 variables (columns) represent daily temperatures, which I then wished to subset into twelve separate data frames for each month of the year. The following code does this:

```
TAS1.JAN = subset(TAS1, select=(grepl("-01-", colnames(TAS1))))
TAS1.FEB = subset(TAS1, select=(grepl("-02-", colnames(TAS1))))
TAS1.MAR = subset(TAS1, select=(grepl("-03-", colnames(TAS1))))
TAS1.APR = subset(TAS1, select=(grepl("-04-", colnames(TAS1))))
TAS1.MAY = subset(TAS1, select=(grepl("-05-", colnames(TAS1))))
TAS1.JUN = subset(TAS1, select=(grepl("-06-", colnames(TAS1))))
TAS1.JUL = subset(TAS1, select=(grepl("-07-", colnames(TAS1))))
TAS1.AUG = subset(TAS1, select=(grepl("-08-", colnames(TAS1))))
TAS1.SEP = subset(TAS1, select=(grepl("-09-", colnames(TAS1))))
TAS1.OCT = subset(TAS1, select=(grepl("-10-", colnames(TAS1))))
TAS1.NOV = subset(TAS1, select=(grepl("-11-", colnames(TAS1))))
TAS1.DEC = subset(TAS1, select=(grepl("-12-", colnames(TAS1))))
```

This code is obviously very repetitive though and I'm aware the above should be possible to execute in a line or two. I'm still a very naive programmer though. I know I ought to be using loops or something similar but do not know how to adapt loops for simple code like this. Any suggestions very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split.default` by extracting the month out from the column name.

```
list1 <- split.default(df, sub(".*-(\\d+)-.*", "\\1", names(df)))
```

You could also use `format` to split based on month.

```
list1 <- split.default(df, format(as.Date(names(df)), "%m"))
```

It will give you list of 12 dataframes which can be extracted using `list1[[1]]`, `list1[[2]]`  and so on individually.

Comment: I see that I can run functions such as rowMeans on the list through lapply, but cannot run rowQuantiles. Do you know of an alternative way to calculate row quantiles for lists?

Comment: @DJ-AFC If you want to calculate row-wise quantiles, you might try `lapply(list1, function(x) apply(x, 1, quantile))`

Comment: Thank you @Ronak Shah. This works well. I wish to specify the 99.9th percentile so tried modifying the last bit to read (...apply(x, 1, quantile(c(0.999))) but this doesn't work.

Comment: @DJ-AFC I think you meant `lapply(list_df, function(x) apply(x, 1, quantile, 0.999))` ?

Comment: Silly me - yes this does the trick. It is much much slower than calculating the rowmeans with lapply(df, rowMeans) though. Shame the rowQuantiles function can't be applied to lists in the same way.